# Firefox enforces word-break property based on whitespace existence

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Below are two snippets. They only difference is [HTML-Whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace)-placement and they should, except for the whitespaces, render identically. While this is the case in Chrome, in Firefox they break out of their parent's container.

This raises two questions:

1. Is this expected behavior or a bug?
2. How can I get rid of Firefoxes quirkiness here?

```css
#inner {
  width: 300px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.unit {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Group One:</span>
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
    <span>Three</span>
  </span>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Group Two:</span>
    <span>Four</span>
    <span>Five</span>
    <span>Six</span>
  </span>
  <span class="unit">
    <span>Group Three:</span>
    <span>Seven</span>
    <span>Eight</span>
    <span>Nine</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
#inner {
  width: 300px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.unit {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner"><span class="unit"><span>Group One:</span><span>One</span><span>Two</span><span>Three</span></span><span class="unit"><span>Group Two:</span><span>Four</span><span>Five</span><span>Six</span></span><span class="unit"><span>Group Three:</span><span>Seven</span><span>Eight</span><span>Nine</span></span></div>
```

Comment: maybe the support is not 100% or you discovered a bug

Comment: @TemaniAfif I created a report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1670705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break-all` instead of `break-word` and add `inline-block` to the unit elements

```css
#inner {
  width: 300px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.unit {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner"><span class="unit"><span>Group One:</span><span>One</span><span>Two</span><span>Three</span></span><span class="unit"><span>Group Two:</span><span>Four</span><span>Five</span><span>Six</span></span><span class="unit"><span>Group Three:</span><span>Seven</span><span>Eight</span><span>Nine</span></span></div>
```